# WebGLでのエラーコード

Tags: unity3d

[マルチポスト](https://teratail.com/questions/41811)です。
UnityでWebGL向けに Development Build  したところ実行画面（ブラウザ）で以下のエラーコードが出ました。

```
Could not open file sharedassets0.assets.resS for read
```

エラーコードをそのまま検索したのですが英語のサイトばかりで，内容が把握できません。
これは何を意味しているのですか？そしてどうすれば解決できますか？

補足：関係しているかわかりませんが，Unity上での再生は色が付いているのにWebGLでは色が出ないオブジェクトがありました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/41811)で解決することができました。

> 英語サイトのGoogle翻訳レベルですが 
>   作業途中でプラットフォームを切り替えたことが原因で発生している感じですね。
>   解決した情報として、 
>   プラットフォームの切り替えを行ったら 
>   Unityの再起動、アセットの再インポート、スプライトのアトラスの再作成がありました。 
>   PC自体の再起動もあるようです。
>   新規プロジェクトを作成＆プラットフォームをWebGLに切り替え、 
>   その後で関連アセットをインポート＆ビルドしてエラーになるか確認したらどうでしょうか？